# Installed app not opening

Tags: 18.04, gui

On my Ubuntu 18.04, when I click on the icon for Bitwarden in the applications window, it no longer opens. I've always opened it that way before. That app opens on my other devices. Other apps there open, although sometimes after more time than usual. When I clicked on "details", it was confirmed that it is installed.

When I booted up my computer today, before coming here I tried again to open the app. This time it worked after a delay. If there is a problem with my internet connection, can that cause a failure to open one app, while continuing to work with others?

Comment: Try opening that application using terminal just type in the application name if it's one word most probably it can run

Comment: When I booted up my computer today, before coming here I tried again to open the app. This time it worked after a delay. If there is a problem with my internet connection, can that cause a failure to open one app, while continuing to work with others?

Comment: Not possible. It's only related to BitWarden. These kind of problems can happen when an application is trying to connect to a server and the server is not responding or very slow in response. So it's not related your internet connection. Next time when it is not opening you may check the running programs and see if it is listed there. If it's present, mostly something wrong with BitWarden system. If an app crashes, you would usually find a log in /var/crash diretory.